# js Вывести введенные данные из input в html value="вот сюда"

Tags: javascript, html

Я новичок в js. don't push me pls.

Есть такой код:

```
<input class="out" type="hidden" name="key" value="">

<li>
    <label>
           <input class="t-add" type="text" placeholder="Введите номер">
    </label>
           <button class="btnsub" onclick="addT()">Добавить в виджет</button>
</li>

<script>
function addT() {
document.querySelector('.btnsub').addEventListener('click', ()=>{
    let data = document.querySelector('.t-add').value;
    // document.querySelector('.out').innerHTML = data;
    document.querySelector('.out').innerHTML = value("");
})}
</script>
```

Нужно взять данные введенные из класса t-add, и внести в html value="вот сюда".     


       
UPD:    
А как можно сделать чтобы "Автоматически" данные выводились в Value?  Тоесть чтобы не нажимать btn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы вешаете обработчик события с помощью `onclick` в теге, но в этой функции у вас добавляется еще один `addEventListener('click')`

Измените `addT` функцию на это

```
function addT() {
  let data = document.querySelector('.t-add').value;

  document.querySelector('.out').value = data;
}
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо - помогло. 
Почему использовал событие oncklick т.к без него почему то не работает передача в value))

Answer (score 0):

Вопрос Закрыт, решение найдено.

Если вдруг кому понадобится:
Нужно добавить событие для input'a onkeyup="myFunction"

Подробнее можете почитать здесь:  https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onkeyup.asp